# Один скрипт для игры на движке Unity (разница производительности)

Tags: c#, классы, unity3d, оптимизация, производительность

Есть ли разница в производительности между приложением (на движке Unity) использующем один скрипт (один класс) или несколько скриптов (несколько классов) ?.
P. S. В случае с использованием нескольких скриптов только один MonoBehaviour (остальные подключаемые к нему классы)

Answer (score 3):

Если каждый скрипт вызывает Start() или Update() то, да нагрузка увеличивается. В блоге Unity была на эту тему статья, они рекомендуют для оптимизации, создать один скрипт-менеджер в котором вызывать функцию Update и из нее вызывать внутренние Update'ы каждого скрипта. Однако писать всю логику игры в одном файле **ни в коем случае нельзя**!

[Статью](http://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/) кстати уже перевели на русский.

Comment: `создать один скрипт-менеджер в котором вызывать функцию Update и из нее вызывать внутренние Update'ы` - зависит от игры. Если я пишу тетрис - то производительность вряд ли упадет на столько, что кирпичи будут зависать в воздухе на секунды)) ... и кстати в статье написано `Если быть честным, этот тест не полностью корректен.` бла бла бла `В реальной ситуации управляющий скрипт был бы гораздо сложнее, и его исполнение проходило бы медленнее.` .....так что тут что-то более серьезное для теста надо

Comment: Я хоть слово сказал про жесткие зависания или что то в таком духе? Я просто ссылаюсь на статью в качестве ответа на конкретно поставленный вопрос. Даже если прирост в производительности в реальном тесте будет меньше, что это меняет? Рекомендация Unity использовать менеджер для оптимизации. Если не говорить про тесты, вы видели и сами что большую часть такта занимает именно вызов Update.